# Split long string into array and keep delimiter

Tags: arrays, bash

I've got a strange edge-case.
I have a long string which contains `\n` (newline characters).
So the string looks something like:

```
text="loremipsum\nDollor sit atmet \n aliquyam erat, 
sed diam\naliquyam erat \n sed diam"
```

I need to split the string into an array, but keep the newline characters uniterpreted,
so the array/output looks like:

```
"loremipsum\n"
"Dollor sit atmet \n"
"aliquyam erat, sed diam\n"
"aliquyam erat \n"
"sed diam"
```

I couldn't find a way to split the string and preserve the `\n` characters.
If I use `IFS=$"\n"` the `\n`characters are deleted,
but if I use `IFS="\n"` it gets split and delets all occurrence of `n`.
I tried it like:

```
IFS=$"\n" read -d '' -a arr <<<"$text"
```

How can I solve this?

### Clarification/Update

The `text` is dynamic and can be very long 3000+ chars,
so creating the array like: `declare -a arr=([0]=$'loremipsum\n'...` is not an option.
The `\n` characters (0x5c + 0x6e in ascii code) should all be treated the same,
the should **not** be replaced with an actual newline.
The `\n` characters **must** be preserved,
because the progrann which gets the output looks for these in plaintext.
The `\n` characters can be àt every position in a sentence,
also in a word like:
`lor\nem` or with spaces: `Lorem \n ipsum`
So the `\n` characters must be at the end of the elements inside the array, like shown above.
The text must only be splitted at `\n` not a spaces etc..

Comment: Is there any reason you cant just append the "\n" back to each line?

Comment: Let me confirm about the newline characters in your text.
The substring `loremipsum` is followed by literal character "\" + "n"
(0x5c + 0x6e in ascii code) and `aliquyam erat,` is followed by
a newline code (0x0a in ascii code) right?

Comment: I added a Clarification

Answer (score 3):

You can use *process substitution* and `echo`, e.g.

```
text="loremipsum\nDollor sit atmet \n aliquyam erat, sed diam\naliquyam erat \n sed diam"
readarray arr < <(echo -e "$text")
```

You can also use `printf` in the *process substitution* as well, e.g.

```
< <(printf "$text")
```

Since the `-t` option is not give to `readarray`, the `'\n'` is included as part of the array element.

**Example Use/Output**

Adding a `declare -p arr` to output the array, you would have:

```
text="loremipsum\nDollor sit atmet \n aliquyam erat, sed diam\naliquyam erat \n sed diam"
readarray arr < <(echo -e "$text")
declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]=$'loremipsum\n' [1]=$'Dollor sit atmet \n' [2]=$' aliquyam erat, sed diam\n' [3]=$'aliquyam erat \n' [4]=$' sed diam\n')
```

If you want to trim leading whitespace, you can use the brace-expansion `${element#*[[:space:]]}`. Up to you.

Comment: https://repl.it/@leagris/DamagedDearestFacts `readarray arr <<<"${text@E}"`

Comment: Yes, the additional expansions are nice -- that would make a nice separate answer (I guess "*Parameter transformation*" is the correct term `:)`

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but I can't do it like this. Please look at the update.

Comment: Understand `declare -a ...` is the output of `declare -p ...` -- that was just used to show you what is in the content of the array. `readarray arr < <(echo -e "$text")` loads the array -- you can do whatever you need to with it afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding from the sample (input/output) data given:

- there is one actual newline character in `text` (between `erat,` and `sed diem`); this is to be removed and assuming there is no (space) after `erat,` we need to add a (space), ie, replace the actual newline character with a (space)
- there are 4 literal strings of `\` + `n`; we are to break the array after these literals; the literal `\` + `n` are to remain in the text that is stored in the array
- the output should have a leading space removed from array values
- I'm assuming the final results should **not** include the double quotes (ie, OP included the double quotes in the desired output as a means of delimiting the array values for display purposes)

One idea:

```
text="loremipsum\nDollor sit atmet \n aliquyam erat,
sed diam\naliquyam erat \n sed diam"

# convert actual newline character to a (space)

text=${text//$'\n'/ }

# add an actual newline character after the literal `\` + `n`

text=${text//\n/\n$'\n'}

# print our value, remove leading (space), and load into array

IFS=$'\n' arr=( $(printf "%s\n" "${text}." | sed 's/^ //g') )

# display array

typeset -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="loremipsum\\n" [1]="Dollor sit atmet \\n" [2]="aliquyam erat, sed diam\\n" [3]="aliquyam erat \\n" [4]="sed diam.")

# loop through array and display individual strings; add double quotes as delimiters for display purposes

for i in "${!arr[@]}"
do
   echo "\"${arr[${i}]}\""
done

"loremipsum\n"
"Dollor sit atmet \n"
"aliquyam erat, sed diam\n"
"aliquyam erat \n"
"sed diam."
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but I can't do it like this. Please look at the update.